# What is the purpose of working on a logit scale in partial dependence plots?

Tags: r, random-forest

What is the purpose of working on a logit scale in partial dependence plots (in binary classification)?

One could simply go about as follows:

1. Grow a forest
2. Suppose `x` has `v` distinct values in the training data set. Construct `v` data sets as follows. For each of the `v` values of `x` make up a new data `se` where `x` only takes on that value, leaving all the other values untouched.
3. For each of the `v` data sets thus obtained, predict the response using random forest.
4. For each of the `v` data sets, average these predictions
5. Plot `v` and the corresponding averaged predictions

Instead of just doing that, in literature they go on and replace step 4 and 5 by (see also partialPlot in R package randomForest):

Step 4.Compute `average(log(predictions)-0.5(log(predicions) + log(1-predictions)))=average(0.5 logit(predictions))`

Step 5.Plot `v` and the corresponding computed `1/2 logit(predictions)`

Why?

Comment: Perhaps there is a theoretical objection to averaging probabilities?  I faced this issue in my `plotmo` package, and made some comments on it in Section 9.3 of the package vignette ([link](http://www.milbo.org/doc/plotmo-notes.pdf)).